# Block Art - IEEEXtreme 9.0

Tags: c++, programming-challenge, time-limit-exceeded

I attempted [this](https://ieee.hackerrank.com/contests/ieeextreme9/challenges/block-art/copy-from/45458) problem from the ieeextreme, and I got timeout for just over 40% of the cases. Now that the competition is over, I was wondering what could be improved.

The problem is as follows:

> Given a grid of size R, C
>
> 1 <= r <= 12, 1 <= c <= 10^6
>
> Apply one of 3 commands 'a', 'r', or 'q'
>
> 'a', x1, y1, x2, y2: add one to each element of the subgrid formed by the co-ordinates given
>
> 'r', x1, y1, x2, y2: remove one from each element of the subgrid formed by the co-ordinates given
>
> 'q', x1, y1, x2, y2: output the sum of the elements in the subgrid formed by the co-ordinates given

I gave a naive solution as seen below, where I simulated the grid with a 2d array, and applied each operation as it came.

I also tried to implement an array of fenwick trees, but that solution gave more timeouts, so I believe there are a lot more add and remove commands than query.

Code:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

void inp(int &n) 
 {
    n = 0;
    int ch = getchar_unlocked();
    while(ch < '0' || ch > '9')
    {
        ch = getchar_unlocked();
    }

    while(ch >= '0' && ch <= '9')
    {
        n = (n<<3)+(n<<1) + ch-'0', ch=getchar_unlocked();
    }
  }  

int grid[13][1000001];

int main() {
    int R, C;
    inp(R);
    inp(C);

    for(int i = 0; i < R; ++i) {
        for(int j = 0; j < C; ++j) {
            grid[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
    
    int Q;
    inp(Q);
    while(Q--) {
        char o;
        int x1, y1, x2, y2;
        cin >> o;
        inp(x1);
        inp(y1);
        inp(x2);
        inp(y2);
        if(o == 'a') {
            for(int i = x1; i <= x2; ++i) {
                for(int j = y1; j <= y2; ++j) {
                    ++grid[i][j];
                }
            }
        } else if(o == 'r') {
            for(int i = x1; i <= x2; ++i) {
                for(int j = y1; j <= y2; ++j) {
                    --grid[i][j];
                }
            }
        } else {
            int count = 0;
            for(int i = x1; i <= x2; ++i) {
                for(int j = y1; j <= y2; ++j) {
                    count += grid[i][j];
                }
            }
            cout << count << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: This is the solution with the fenwick tree, which gave more timeouts

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

#define LSOne(S) (S & (-S))

int ft[13][1000003];
int size = 1000003;

int sum(int i, int b) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (; b; b -= LSOne(b)) sum += ft[i][b];
    return sum;
}

int sum(int i, int a, int b) {
    return sum(i, b) - (a == 1 ? 0 : sum(i, a - 1));
}

void update(int i, int k, int v) {
    for (; k <= size; k += LSOne(k)) ft[i][k] += v;
}

void inp( int &n ) 
 {
    n=0;
    int ch=getchar_unlocked();;
    while( ch < '0' || ch > '9' ){
        ch=getchar_unlocked();
    }

    while(  ch >= '0' && ch <= '9' )
        n = (n<<3)+(n<<1) + ch-'0', ch=getchar_unlocked();
  }  


int main() {
    int R, C;
    inp(R);
    inp(C);
    size = C;
    
    int Q;
    inp(Q);
    while(Q--) {
        char o;
        int x1, y1, x2, y2;
        cin >> o;
        inp(x1);
        inp(y1);
        inp(x2);
        inp(y2);
        
        if(o == 'a') {
            for(int i = x1; i <= x2; ++i) {
                for(int j = y1; j <= y2; ++j) {
                    update(i, j, 1);
                }
            }
        } else if(o == 'r') {
            for(int i = x1; i <= x2; ++i) {
                for(int j = y1; j <= y2; ++j) {
                    update(i, j, -1);
                }
            }
        } else {
            int count = 0;
            for(int i = x1; i <= x2; ++i) {
                count += sum(i, y1, y2);
            }
            cout << count << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Fenwick trees

It's too bad you didn't print your Fenwick tree solution, because there was probably something wrong with it if it gave your more timeouts than the brute force solution that you provided.

Assuming you had an array of 12 Fenwick trees (because the rows are limited to 12), each add/remove operation should only take up to \$O(r \log c)\$ time, compared to \$O(r*c)\$ time of the brute force solution.  Each query should take also take \$(r \log c)\$ time instead of \$O(r*c)\$ time.

## 2-d Fenwick tree

There also exists a 2-d version of the fenwick tree, which is perfectly suited to this problem.  It should be slightly faster at \$O(\log r * \log c)\$ time.  [Here is a sample implementation of a 2-d Fenwick tree.](https://sites.google.com/site/indy256/algo/fenwick_tree_2d)  However, since `r` in your case is 12, it's unclear whether this would actually be faster than the array of Fenwick trees or not.

## Edit: Comments on your 2nd solution

You didn't implement the Fenwick tree correctly.  When you updated it, you did this:

> ```
>     if(o == 'a') {
>         for(int i = x1; i <= x2; ++i) {
>             for(int j = y1; j <= y2; ++j) {
>                 update(i, j, 1);
>             }
>         }
>     }
> ```

What it should have looked like is this:

```
    if(o == 'a') {
        for(int i = x1; i <= x2; ++i) {
            update(i, y1,    1);
            update(i, y2+1, -1);
        }
    }
```

Notice the lack of a loop across the `y` values.  The same thing applies to the remove operation.

Comment: I can add it in if you would like, it is very similar to the original

Answer (score 0):

Look the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33149244/formula-for-find-empty-space/33174018#33174018) I gave to a question like this.

I think the data structure you must implement should take care of the shape of the elements you are going to move.

In the link you'll find a list of rectangles that can only be **on**, just add a counter so that they can count how many blocks they are **tall**.

Hope this helps, if you want something more just ask.